# What is this ciiycode.com thing?

Tags: discussion

I am sure a lot of you noticed already: Some websites like ciiycode.com appeared all of a sudden (I think I saw another one like this a while ago). They appear to parse stack**overflow**. For example the "stack**overflow** question" [How to integrate greenDAO with JSON Jackson and handle many to many relation mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374306/how-to-integrate-greendao-with-json-jackson-and-handle-many-to-many-relation-map) looks like this there ([link](http://www.codeitive.com/0SSjPjXVPV/how-to-integrate-greendao-with-json-jackson-and-handle-many-to-many-relation-mapping.html)):

[image]

The most annoying thing is that they seem to trick google and the're getting a quite high ranking for a lot of questions.

They are not affiliated with the stack-exchange network, are they?  Are the stack-exchange owners on it to get those pages down or couldn't they care less?

I was just wondering because since a few days/weeks this sites starts to annoy me.